# AVPlayer delay when streaming AAC audio via HTTP

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to stream an AAC audio from external server via HTTP like this:

```
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myStreamURL]];
[player play];
```

This method works (it indeed plays audio) but not in a way I want it to work. The problem is that there is a very long delay (30 seconds) after invoking play method, then I have to wait 30 seconds looking on a spinning "downloading wheel" on status bar, and the audio plays fine but always after this delay, not earlier.

I think it actually downloads the audio, and plays it after it instead of streaming it.

I haven't figured how to resolve this issue so far, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the audio server, but what I do with AVPlayer is to observe  `player.currentItem.status` property by KVO. When it becomes `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`, invoke `prerollAtRate`. Then start playing within its completion handler.

```
[player prerollAtRate:1.0 completionHandler:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
        [player play];
    }
}];
```

Anyway, first it is recommended to observe `"status"`,  `"currentItem.status"` and `"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"` key paths on the AVPlayer instance, and log them when and how they change. You will see which part takes long time.